# UIMapView has a delegate set but it never gets called

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I had created a `UIMapView` and set delegate, but it's not called delegate of mapview.

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface MapViewController : UIView <MKMapViewDelegate>
- (id)initWith_Latitude:(NSString *)Latitude Longitude:(NSString *)Longitude;

- (id)initWith_Latitude:(NSString *)Latitude Longitude:(NSString *)Longitude
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;
        [mapView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [mapView setDelegate:self];
        mapRegion.center.latitude = [Latitude doubleValue];
        mapRegion.center.longitude = [Longitude doubleValue];
        mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.005;
        mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.005;
        mapView.region = mapRegion;
        [self addSubview:mapView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

delegate is not called:

```
- (void)mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView2 fullyRendered:(BOOL)fullyRendered{
    NSLog(@"abc...");
}
```

How to I can resolve this problem, please help me.

Comment: are other delegate methods called - most importantly maybe 'mapViewDidFailLoadingMap'

Comment: and to double check.. the initWith_ method is in the same class as the mapViewDidFinish.. method, yes?

Comment: I had created a class UIView, in my view. I created UIMapView and set delegate for it and call delegate of uimapview in this class.

Comment: sorry I don't get it